# Finding the least possible order of D.E given the particular solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let

$$
y=x^2 \exp (3x) + \sin x
$$

be solution of initial value problem with constant coefficients then what is the least possible order of differential equation if y solves the homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients?

Is it 2 or 3 or 4 or 5?

I know that the first term of the solution corresponds to the  factor $$(D-3) ^3$$ & the second term corresponds to the factor $$((D^2 )+1)$$ of  D.E     $$f(D)y =0$$ where

$f(D)$ is linear differential order.

So the D.E is  $$[ ((D-3) ^3)     ((D^2) +1) ]y = 0$$

Further solving the above D.E gives order =5.

So the answer comes to be 5.
It is asked to find least possible order and order is nothing but the highest order of differential coefficient. Then why the  word 'least possible' used here?

What role it does in this question?

Comment: You do not give the full originally question. I guess it is assumed that $y$ solves a _linear_ and _homogeneous_ differential equation _with constant coefficients_?

Comment: @mickep You are absolutely correct

Comment: Please help me to confirm my answer, I dont think the question is too difficult to be answered by mathematicians here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an argument that
$$
f(D)=(D-3)^3(D^2+1)P(D)
$$
for some polynomial $P$. Thus, the degree of $f$ is at least $5$. But, we do not know if there are other solutions in $f(D)y=0$, origin from $P$. Thus, we know that the least degree of $f$ is $5$, but we have no upper bound.

For example, the function you mention also solves
$$
(D-3)^3(D^2+1)(D+2)(D-7)y=0.
$$
and
$$
(D-3)^3(D^2+1)y=0.
$$
The first one of these has degree 7, the second degree 5.

Does this answers your question completely?

Comment: Yes absolutely I got the thing. A big thanks .